# How to (efficiently) follow / tail a file with Haskell, including detecting file rotation? (tail -F)

Tags: haskell

In essence I wish to know how to approach implementing `tail -F` Linux command functionality in Haskell. My goal is to follow a log file, such as a web server log file, and compute various real time statistics by parsing the input as it comes in. Ideally with no interruptions if the log file is rotated with `logrotate` or similar service.

I'm somewhat at loss on how to even approach the problem and what should I take into consideration in terms of performance in presence of lazy I/O. Would any of the streaming libraries be relevant here?

Comment: These haskell bindings for inotify could be a start. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hinotify-0.3.9 Does it need to work on Windows?

Comment: Thanks @danidiaz I will take a look at that. Windows support is not required.

Comment: Avoid lazy IO. On the first EOF it will close the file handle, when you want to try reading again from it. Dumb old implementations of `tail -F` used to poll the file continuously trying to read more data every N ms, but on linux inotify is the right™ way to solve this -- no polling needed. (I'm pretty sure Windows and MacOS have something similar nowadays)

Comment: I recently released a small libary (a expanded version of my answer) that should detect file rotation and truncation: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tailfile-hinotify

Answer (score 8):

This is a partial answer, as it doesn't handle file truncation by `logrotate`. It avoids lazy I/O and uses the [bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:hGetSome), [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming), [streaming-bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring) and [hinotify](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hinotify) packages.

Some preliminary imports:

```
{-# language OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal (defaultChunkSize)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming as B
import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
import Control.Concurrent.QSem
import System.INotify
import System.IO (withFile,IOMode(ReadMode))
import System.Environment (getArgs)
```

Here's the "tailing" function:

```
tailing :: FilePath -> (B.ByteString IO () -> IO r) -> IO r
tailing filepath continuation = withINotify $ \i -> do
    sem <- newQSem 1
    addWatch i [Modify] filepath (\_ -> signalQSem sem)
    withFile filepath ReadMode (\h -> continuation (handleToStream sem h))
    where
    handleToStream sem h = B.concat . Streaming.repeats $ do
        lift (waitQSem sem)
        readWithoutClosing h
    -- Can't use B.fromHandle here because annoyingly it closes handle on EOF
    -- instead of just returning, and this causes problems on new appends.
    readWithoutClosing h = do
        c <- lift (Data.ByteString.hGetSome h defaultChunkSize)
        if Data.ByteString.null c
           then return ()
           else do B.chunk c
                   readWithoutClosing h
```

It takes a file path an a callback that consumes a streaming bytestring.

The idea is that, each time before reading from the handle until EOF, we decrement a semaphore, which is only increased by the callback that is invoked when the file is modified.

We can test the function like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    filepath : _ <- getArgs
    tailing filepath B.stdout
```

Comment: Some useful related links: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41668/what-happens-when-you-read-a-file-while-it-is-overwritten http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39509/59909